# NetLogo: Is there any way to change patch colour under turtles which dies?

Tags: netlogo

I wrote a simulation which contain `ants and spiders`. **spider** will kill **ants** and not things will happens however **spider** will take some of **ant venom** and reduces health. At some certain point **spider** will die after there energy is equal **0** . I want spider to die and change patch colours under death spider from black to brown

I have tried this code but it didn't work .**spider** just disappear (die) but pcolor is not change

```
to spider-death  
  if energy  <= 0 [ask antiagents-here [die if pcolor = black [set pcolor brown]]]
end
```

please help

Answer (score 2):

After an agent dies, it no longer exists, and therefore can no longer take any actions.

So for example:

```
ask turtles [
  die
  print "hello!"
]
```

Nothing will ever be printed, because the turtle dies before it can print anything.

So in your code, you just need to change this part:

```
die if pcolor = black [set pcolor brown]
```

to:

```
if pcolor = black [set pcolor brown] die
```

Comment: It is still not working however spider just die without changing patch color under it

to spider-death  ;; turtle procedure
  
  if energy  <= 0 [ask antiagents-here [if pcolor = black [set pcolor brown] die]]

Comment: There is nothing else incorrect in the code you posted, so whatever the problem is, it must have to do with the broader context. Try adding some print statements to check your understanding of what's going on.

Comment: I am quite new to this program is it possible that can you please show me how to do it

Comment: Well so for example if you change it to `if pcolor = black [ set pcolor brown show "hello!" ] die` but it never prints "hello!", you know that part of the code isn't even running.

Comment: I try it still no hello show up  , Really have no idea now ?

Comment: I have answered your present question. Ask a new question, include more code and more information about what you tried and what you found.